# php within js-file Wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

In a .js-file, I need to get the template-directory of a Wordpress theme, i.e. I need to get the return-value of  `<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>` within the js-file.

The idea is something like:

```
var blogTemplateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>";
```

How can this be achieved? What is the standard (Wordpress) way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Erik earlier posted, the file extension for the JavaScript-file is meaningless, as it in the end all comes down to the content. Upon encountering this situation during development, I found that I needed to add the following to the top of the so called JavaScript-file:

```
<?php

   //Let's set the header straight
   header('Content-type: text/javascript');

   //Get the WP-specifics, so that we can use constants and what not
   $home_dir = preg_replace('^wp-content/plugins/[a-z0-9\-/]+^', '', getcwd());
   include($home_dir . 'wp-load.php');
?>
```

This ensures that you get the definitions into your JavaScript-file, and you can use the example above with themes too (just make sure you change the `/plugins` into `/themes` instead).

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking if I do `<script type="text/javascript">
var templateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>";
</script>` within header.php, why can't I access the value of `templateDir` within my .js-file. Is there a way to get this to work, caus then I could keep my js-files?

Comment: Well, are you setting `templateDir` before loading the other JavaScript-files? If so, it should be possible to use the variables in your js-files.

`File 1 (index.php): http://pastebin.com/sQGnmM9S` 
`File 2 (javascript.js): http://pastebin.com/cnUv5inD`

Comment: Thank you, I had gotten the order wrong earlier. Now it works! :)

Comment: Thanks was sure how to import all the variables in JS.  NB: For anyone else doing this in a theme, swap /plugins/ for /themes/ in the above code

Answer (score 15):

Wordpress offers a `wp_localize_script()` function that allows you to pass a PHP array to a .js file when you register it with Wordpress.

**It works like this**

1) Register your script with Wordpress using [wp_register_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script);
Build an array of your parameters that you want to send to the script.

```
wp_enqueue_script('my-script','/path/to/script.js');
```

2) Build an array of your parameters that you want to send to the script.

```
$params = array('foo' => 'bar','setting' => 123);
```

3) Call [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) and give your parameters a unique name.

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'MyScriptParams', $params );
```

4) You can access the variables in JavaScript as follows:

```
<script>
alert(object_name.some_string);
</script>
```

**Note:** you need to use wp_enqueue_script() when you want Wordpress to incluse the JavaScript file in the header.

**Pulling it all together**

```
<?php
$myPlugin = new MyPlugin();

//Add some JS to the admin section
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', array($myPlugin, 'adminJavaScript'));

class MyPlugin{

        public function adminJavaScript() {

        $settings = array(
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'setting' => 123
        );

        wp_register_script('myJavaScriptName', plugins_url('/myJavaScript.min.js', __FILE__));
        wp_localize_script('myJavaScriptName', 'settings', $settings); //pass any php settings to javascript
        wp_enqueue_script('myJavaScriptName'); //load the JavaScript file
    }
}
?>

<script>
    alert(settings.foo);
</script>
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I've been working with Wordpress for like 5 years and I didn't know about `wp_localize_script()`. I just used this technique in my current project and it worked flawlessly. This clearly seems to me to be the most correct way to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The file extension for a javascript file is meaningless. You can use PHP to output your javascript file just like you do HTML pages. Include the JS file as:

```
<script src="my_javascript_file.php"></script>
```

And then you can use the line from your question in your javascript file:

```
var blogTemplateDir = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory');?>";
```

Comment: Using `<script src="my_javascript_file.php"></script>` leads to weird errors in other files. Don't ask me, it just kills my page. If I do `<?php require "my_javascript_file.php" ?>` instead, then it works. Also, if I follow this solution, I have to wrap all my js-code into `<script type="text/javascript"><script>` in my (ex-)js-file. It does work this way, however since I was looking for a solution which allows me to keep my js-file, I've decided to mark ninetwozero's answer as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the .js in a .php file and just include it in your context.